# Undefined is not an object (evaluating T.State) - React Native

Tags: react-native

I can't seem to load my app since this error appears. I think it has something to do with `react-navigation`?

[image: Error log]

[image: Error log]

Here is the snippet where I used `createStackNavigator`

```
const MyTracker = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Games: {screen: Games},
        Standings: {screen: Standings}
    }, 
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Games',
        transitionConfig: () => ({
            transitionSpec: {
                duration: 0
            }
        })
    });

const MainContainer = createAppContainer(MyTracker);

export default MainContainer;
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by downgrading my `react-navigation` to `2.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

I never ran on this problem with react-navigation, i think it´s because transitionConfig is a function, Yes, but it should RETURN something don't you know? 
try this

```
transitionConfig: () => (
           return {
            transitionSpec: {
                duration: 0
            }
        })
```

Comment: If you want to know more about transitionConfig check this article, it's awesome https://medium.com/async-la/custom-transitions-in-react-navigation-2f759408a053

Comment: Try deleting transitionConfig

Comment: If that doesn't work i don't think that it's a problem with react navigation, it may be related to one of your screens/ modules